# ¿Responder preguntas que son referenciables a otra respuesta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, duplicados-exactos

Supongamos que un usuario, más bien inexperto o novato en el sitio, realiza una pregunta que denota que estuvo investigando (al menos lo mínimo indispensable como para formular una pregunta correcta).

¿Qué es preferible hacer?

- Brindar una respuesta que pueda brindar una explicación más completa y adecuada a la problemática particular que plantea el OP, o
- Introducir un comentario con los enlaces hacia preguntas relacionadas para que el OP, mediante el análisis de esas respuestas, pueda asociarlas a su problema y finalmente dar con una solución

O formulado de otra manera más resumida, ¿vale la pena que el OP pueda llegar a una solución "*más rápido*", o esas respuestas no hacen más que duplicar información de los mismos problemas?

Comment: Creo que Marcos no se refiere a duplicados exactos sino a preguntas en las que el problema de raíz es el mismo, y que si el usuario abstrajera un poco la solución de la otra pregunta le serviría para responder su pregunta.

Comment: @Alvaro, sí, así parece. No encontré etiqueta más apropiada para clasificar. De todos modos, parece un caso de duplicados si no hay mayor "cocimiento" que juntar enlaces a otros duplicados. Probablemente lo indicado es dejar los enlaces en los comentarios y ver si el OP lo estudia. Si tras ese paso no puede llegar a la solución, ya sería pertinente contestarle. Ell objetivo es ir contestando cosas nuevas cada vez.

Comment: Exacto, me refería a situaciones donde si bien la respuesta no se obtiene de manera inmediata (al no ser una pregunta duplicada), el OP podria llegar a un resultado a partir de abstraerse e inferir de otras respuestas. La duda por la cual planteo esta pregunta es que es lo correcto dado las normas del sitio, una opcion seria confiar en la capacidad del OP de lograr llegar a la solución y otra sería facilitarlo. Supongo que lo indicado sería lo que @fedorqui manifiesta, dejar la pregunta sin respuesta y llevar la discusion a los comentarios con los links.

Answer (score 2):

Cabe recordar que toda pregunta debería estar redactada con la calidad esperada del sitio, de lo contrario existen los motivos de cierre y se puede hacer uso de ellos.

Luego, si la pregunta es válida para el sitio, se evaluaría si tiene un duplicado exacto o no. Si la pregunta tiene su duplicado exacto, entonces votamos a cierre por duplicado.

El tema que tratas aquí es cuando *no es un duplicado exacto, pero su causa raíz es la misma que está expuesta en otra pregunta*. Pues bien, en esos casos, deberíamos revisar si puede llegar a ser un duplicado. Te pongo un ejemplo para la etiqueta [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Existe la pregunta [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42977/227) que básicamente indica cómo tratar un problema ocasionado por una variable con valor `null` (esto existe en muchos LPs. Bueno, ahora apuntando a un framework de Java, específicamente [spring](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring), puedes tener problemas que lucen como `NullPointerException` pero que la pregunta anterior **no resuelve**. Si bien la variable puede ser nula, se debe investigar por qué el framework no pudo asignarle un valor. En este caso, si alguien preguntara algo como "¿Por qué obtengo un NullPointerException con Spring en este caso?" se debería evaluar qué problemas hay en su configuración. Ojo, la pregunta expuesta al comienzo está relacionada pero no brinda la solución concreta. En mi respuesta, podría incluir el enlace a esta pregunta para que los lectores indaguen en mayor información al respecto.